# Django Jet dashboard not showing correctly after upgrade

Tags: python, css, django, django-oscar, django-jet

I have a site running on Django, and I'm trying to install Oscar on it to add an e-commerce app onto it. I'm using Jet as the admin dashboard, and due to a problem with app naming conflicts (both Oscar and Jet have an app named "dashboard", which was fixed in version 1.0.0 of Jet), I've had to upgrade from Jet 0.1.4 to 1.0.2 (which in turn upgraded Django from 1.9.6 to 1.9.10).

After the upgrade, I logged into the admin console to make sure nothing had broken, and sure enough, it had:

[Current state of the Jet dashboard (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWefx.png)

At first it seemed like a problem with the CSS files associated to Jet not being where they needed to be, but after copying them over and making sure they all are retrieved with a 200 OK on page load, the dashboard stays like this.

I would obviously prefer to fix this problem without deleting and reinstalling, since there is a fair deal of configuration that I would have to replicate. Any ideas on what direction to take?

Comment: Have you tried dumping all of your static files and re-running `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes, I have, problem persists after doing that. It's how I got the CSS files to be served properly.